# SOAP request to PHP

Tags: php, web-services, soap

The following code is working in SoapUI:

https://webserver.domain.com/Service?server=webserver-prod&webService=WS_Create_Incident

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:WS_Create_Incident">
<soapenv:Header>
    <urn:AuthenticationInfo>
        <urn:userName>username@domain.com</urn:userName>
        <urn:password>Scrambled</urn:password>
    </urn:AuthenticationInfo>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
    <urn:HelpDesk_Submit_Service>
        <urn:Assigned_Group>GROUP</urn:Assigned_Group>
        <urn:Assigned_Support_Company>COMPANY</urn:Assigned_Support_Company>
        <urn:Assigned_Support_Organization>ORGANIZATION</urn:Assigned_Support_Organization>
    </urn:HelpDesk_Submit_Service>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I have installed soap extension on my test php server. How can I make this request using php?

Answer (score 0):

Try looking up SOAP examples in PHP Manual: http://php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://www....com/.../?WSDL');
$client->__getFunctions();
$client->__getTypes();
```